# Edit text in columns

Tags: sql, mysql, phpmyadmin

Just wondering if someone can assist me with the following issue.

I have a database in MySQL and I'm using PHPMyAdmin to interact with the database.

So within the table example_table_name I have two columns `product_item_short` and `product_item_long` which have URL's in them. Now there is 3000 rows of data and as an example the URL in each starts with `data/image/someimage.png`.

In both columns I need to remove the `data/` and I would like to know how I could so this in SQL.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE example_table
SET product_item_short = SUBSTRING(product_item_short,6),
    product_item_long = SUBSTRING(product_item_long,6);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`SUBSTR()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_substr) function:

```
UPDATE your_table 
SET    product_item_short = SUBSTR(product_item_short, 6),
       product_item_long = SUBSTR(product_item_long, 6);
```

Test case:

```
CREATE TABLE your_table (
    id int, 
    product_item_short varchar(50), 
    product_item_long varchar(50)
);


INSERT INTO your_table VALUES (1, 'data/image/someimage.png',         'data/image/someimage.png');
INSERT INTO your_table VALUES (2, 'data/other-folder/someimage.png',  'data/other-folder/someimage.png');
INSERT INTO your_table VALUES (3, 'data/no-folder.png',               'data/no-folder.png');
INSERT INTO your_table VALUES (4, 'data/image/path/three-levels.png', 'data/image/path/three-levels.png');
```

Result after `UPDATE`:

```
SELECT * FROM your_table;
+------+-----------------------------+-----------------------------+
| id   | product_item_short          | product_item_long           |
+------+-----------------------------+-----------------------------+
|    1 | image/someimage.png         | image/someimage.png         |
|    2 | other-folder/someimage.png  | other-folder/someimage.png  |
|    3 | no-folder.png               | no-folder.png               |
|    4 | image/path/three-levels.png | image/path/three-levels.png |
+------+-----------------------------+-----------------------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

---

**UPDATE:**

If you a solution that eliminates the first directory of the path, whether it is `data/` or `anything-else/`, you may want to use the [`LOCATE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_locate) function, as [@Frank's suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3578902/edit-text-in-columns/3578967#3578967) in another answer:

```
UPDATE your_table 
SET    product_item_short = SUBSTR(product_item_short, LOCATE('/', product_item_short) + 1),
       product_item_long = SUBSTR(product_item_long, LOCATE('/', product_item_long) + 1);
```

Comment: Hi,

Thanks for that.

So, if this is the image URL: data/image/someimage.jpg if I use the above SQL it will strip out the data/ element only?

Comment: @Bill: It will strip the first 5 characters actually. I've updated my answer with a test case. Check out if this is what you are looking for :)

Comment: @Bill: I'm glad this works for you... You may want to mark an answer as accepted by clicking on the green tick, if you found one helpful in solving your problem :)

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE tablename
SET product_item_short = REPLACE(product_item_short, 'data/image/someimage.png', 'newurl/something.png');
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be more flexible than what Daniel described in his answer, you can use something like

```
SUBSTR(product_item_short, LOCATE('/', product_item_short) + 1)
```

which would cut off everything after the first slash.

Comment: Good idea. However note that your arguments are reversed. It should be `LOCATE('/', product_item_short)`. You're also missing the closing parenthesis :)

Comment: I mentioned your solution in my answer... +1 :)